# Does this infinite series over nested logarithm converge?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence, logarithms, infinite-product

Define a sequence $(f_i)_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$ via $f_{i+1}(n)=\log(f_i(n)+1)$ and $f_0(n)=n$. Does the sequence
$$\left(\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{\prod_{j=0}^i f_j(n)}\right)_{i\in\mathbb{N}_0}$$
converge?
If not, are there values for $i$, such that the sum converges? The first three elements
$$\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n}$$
$$\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n\log(n+1)}$$
$$\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n\log(n+1)\log(\log(n+1)+1)}$$
for example all diverge.